# Javascript text to link replacing

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to replace text into link in

Link must be look like " href="/search?q=$oldtext" title="$oldtext" ".
$oldtext is text to replace.

I'm tried to use loop to find text with regexp "/^\x23\w/",and replacing with variable that contain generated link.
And it result to nothing.
I've edit regexp to "/\x23/" and get replacing for "#" (\x23 in hex as I hope=)) char only  in the text mode=(

Help me, I'm stuck

Update:
I have text block between [span class="text2replace"]super text #replacemetolink[/span]
I need to replace #replacemetolink into link [a href="/timeline/search?q=#replacemetolink" title="#replacemetolink" class="search-link"].
I'm triying to make usejs for Opera to Twitter to replace #hashtags into link for searching this hashtag using Twitter search

Comment: Why are you trying to find text with a '#' in it? That character doesn't appear anywhere in the string you want to modify. Can you edit the question to explain what you are trying to do more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var newText = 'Query';
var link = ' href="/search?q=$oldtext" title="$oldtext" ';
link.replace("$oldtext", newText);
```

That would replace all instances of '$oldtext' with the string stored in newText.

Kyle

Comment: Maybe I'd make wrong description, but I have text(!) and need to replace this text with link!Text is between <span> with own class "text2replace"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are talking about, why don't you post some sample text and what it would look like after you replaced it.